# Facebook Audience Network gives very low bid response. Main reason "No Facebook profile found"

Tags: android, facebook-audience-network, mobile-ad-mediation, applovin

I have integrated my Android app to Applovin (MAX) platform and added Facebook bidding as described on documentation. Waited several days to collect some performance data. Now, when I look at bidding performance on Facebook, I see that I have a very low bidding response. It is less than 10%.
[image]

When I click on to "See no bids" link, I see that the main reason is "No Facebook profile found". I think something is wrong here because I don't think FAN requires everyone to make their user login into Facebook. Also, I am quite sure at least 60% of my users are FB users and there is login data on their device. So, probably somehow this data is not collected?

I have checked "Publisher Onboarding Debugger" on the Facebook side and everything shows fine there so it means I did integration correctly.

Has anyone had the same issue? How did you fix it? Maybe I forgot to include something on my app Gradle file? Some Google services that are required and I don't know about it may be.

BTW: I am not using Admob because it was disabled for some unclear for me reason and appealing gave no result. That is why I moved to Applovin.

[image]

Comment: You can check step by step https://dash.applovin.com/documentation/mediation/android/mediation-adapters?network=FACEBOOK_MEDIATE

Comment: @CườngNguyễn I have done everything that is written there but still have 7% fill rate :(

Comment: Sent 10k bid requests, and FB show no bid rate info, nothing. There must be something wrong with AppLovin SDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that problem was a banner ad. The auto-refresh was set on that ad unit and looks like it was sending too many bid requests which Facebook wasn't able to respond. That is why there was a big difference in bid requests and responses. Just turn off auto-refresh if you are using a banner ad as a mediation.

Comment: where we turn off this option max dashboard or audience network dashboard?

Comment: @gturedi You can find it in Applovin MAX. You have to edit each Banner ad unit and In my case the default was set to "MAX Optimized" , I moved it to 5 minutes.

Comment: @TechyRakshak hey man, why is that my app is making more revenue with applovin max than with meta audience, also I checked advanced reporting and the win rate of max is higher than of meta

Comment: Can't point any exact issue. BUT Maybe you have given a bid floor which could be too high for the App Audience, That's Why Facebook is Lossing Bids and Applovin is showing Ads of it's own by giving you low eCPM.

NOTE : That you have not clearly stated that how Applovin is making more revenue? Does it gives high eCPM as compared to FAN.

Comment: @TechyRakshak I saw on advanced reporting that fill rate is 27 % while applovin is 97, ecpm is much higher for audience.